# Restart ProtonVPN after suspend with systemd service not working Ubuntu

Tags: service, vpn, systemd, resume, suspend

I'm trying to set up a Systemd service that would restart my VPN connection (ProtonVPN) after resuming from suspend.
The command that does what I need is `sudo protonvpn r`.
So here is what I did: I created a service `/etc/systemd/system/protonvpn-restart.service`, containing the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Restart ProtonVPN after suspend
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/pvpn-resume
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

and a script `/bin/pvpn-resume` (I made sure it was executable) containing the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

protonvpn r
```

Then I ran `sudo systemctl start protonvpn-restart.service && sudo systemctl enable protonvpn-restart.service`.
But in the end, when I suspend and come back, the VPN doesn't restart and I my Internet won't work until I run manually `sudo protonvpn r`.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Dude did you find a solution to this? Because I want to the same, but i can't just a beginner. Anyway you could try posting these on: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonVPN/ .I'll do it later

Comment: This post has a solution to this: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonVPN/comments/i2f7j5/solution_to_reconnecting_protonvpn_after/ . Maybe you can look up for it, and if it's not working either, then you can try post a question in protonvpn reddit or github issues.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, it works like a charm!! I'll mark this thread as solved and it's thanks to you!